# how to query full name with null values in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access

This is my code in ms access in giving the full name with null values
lname for last name
fname for first name
mname for middle name (change into initial)
x     for name extensions like Jr., Sr., III ect.

this is the code.

[lname] & ", " & [fname] & " " & IIf(IsNull([x]),"",([x]) & ", ") & " " & IIf(IsNull(Left([mname],1)),"",(Left([mname],1)) & ".")

but when i try it to mysql it does not give any data. anyone is free to edit or reconstruct my code to fit the qualifications in mysql query. SALAMAT, MABUHAY

Comment: How are you querying your MySQL? Where is the database? You need to give more info..

Comment: MySQL neither knows iif nor &. use concat() to join strings in mysql or ask the right question to get the right answer!